# Is this type of mysql search effective, should it be changed? Using UNION for multiple tables/different fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a search for website. I have multiple columns and different fields like this:

1. **tmp_auction_auto**

   id order category manufacturer model price price_type location year run run_type doors airbags gear engine horsepower cylinders drivetype fuel color abs electronicwindows climatcontrol disks hatch boardcomputer alarm rightsteer turbo parkingcontrol conditioner leathersalon navigation centrallock chairwarm hydraulics noprice rent exchange customclearance status other contact
2. **tmp_auction_estate** 
   id order type transaction price price_type price_sqm noprice city address area height repair condition project destination land veranda mansard conference stairs_total stair rooms bedrooms balcony sanitary_arr loggia fireplace conditioner garage parking land_destination buildings distance_central_street distance_tbilisi storeroom jacuzzi bathroom shower sauna furniture technique telephone internet generator pool businesscenter ate network inventory wardobe elevator gas hotwater heating intercom cabletv alarmsystem entrancesecurity windowguards security duplex triplex satelite kitchen showcase land_railway land_electricity land_gas land_water land_drainage status other contact
3. **tmp_auction_other** 
   id order title price price_type noprice info contact
4. **tmp_branch** 
   id lang title content x y
5. **tmp_comments** 
   id reply_id path username email title content likes dislikes time admin
6. **tmp_news** 
   id lang title content date
7. **tmp_pages**
   id lang title content date
8. **tmp_presentation** 
   id lang title order

I was wondering how to make a search and finally I did following code:

```
$key = 'a';

$sql = "
SELECT `id`,CONCAT('pages') as `table`,`title` as `title`,`content` as `content` FROM `tmp_pages` WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$key."%' OR `content` LIKE '%".$key."%'
UNION
SELECT `id`,CONCAT('branches') as `table`,`title` as `title`,`content` as `content` FROM `tmp_branch` WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$key."%' OR `content` LIKE '%".$key."%'
UNION
SELECT `id`,CONCAT('auction_auto') as `table`,`manufacturer` as `title`,CONCAT(`manufacturer`,' ',`model`,' / ',`price`,' ',`price_type`) as `content` FROM `tmp_auction_auto` WHERE `manufacturer` LIKE '%".$key."%' OR `model` LIKE '%".$key."%'
UNION
SELECT `id`,CONCAT('auction_estate') as `table`,CONCAT(`city`,' ',`type`) as `title`,CONCAT(`city`,' ',`address`,' / ',`price`,' ',`price_type`) as `content` FROM `tmp_auction_estate` WHERE `other` LIKE '%".$key."%' OR `city` LIKE '%".$key."%'
UNION
SELECT `id`,CONCAT('auction_other') as `table`,`title` as `title`,CONCAT(`title`,' ',' / ',`price`,' ',`price_type`) as `content` FROM `tmp_auction_other` WHERE `info` LIKE '%".$key."%' OR `title` LIKE '%".$key."%'
UNION
SELECT `id`,CONCAT('presentation') as `table`,`title` as `title`,`title` as `contact` FROM `tmp_presentation` WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$key."%'
UNION
SELECT `id`,CONCAT('news') as `table`,`title` as `title`,`content` as `content` FROM `tmp_news` WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$key."%' OR `content` LIKE '%".$key."%'
UNION
SELECT `id`,CONCAT('comments') as `comments`,`title` as `title`,`content` as `content` FROM `tmp_comments` WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$key."%' OR `content` LIKE '%".$key."%'
";
```

As a disadvantage in here I see that there is an existing order of how a script searches for data, I mean if somebody searches `new office` an existing `tmp.pages` will show up first instead of `tmp.news` which is more likely to be relevant.

I have a question, is this type of approach okay? I don't like it for some reason, maybe because I know there is a better alternative to do so, but still I need your opinions, should I leave it like this? Maybe somebody will tell me a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would probably propose a checkboxes for user to choose what areas they want to look at. Also I would give the tables certain importance ranks. Let's say you have a group of important tables which, if any results found, should be displayed first. For example auction_auto, auction_estate, auction_other. Then the rest (or as you wish).

So if someone wants to look for new office, they would check branches, estate, other (example) and since the auction_estate has the greater rank, those results would be first.

For tables that weren't checked, you could run a separate query that would say "We found (xxx) results in News" and so on.

Why would I do it?

Personally I like having the possibility of choosing parts of the site I want to perform a search on. If someone is too lazy, they won't tick the boxes - and the search will be global as you have now. I just think introducing such a feature could be beneficial.

Who doesn't like some power? Even if it's only search engine on the page!